# Cannot Exit Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

UPDATED
This is the minimal reproducible code:
1 > Enter FHSC1014 > Enter new course code > Enter C to quit (failed)

```
#from dict.json 
{"courseInfo": [
        {
            "FHSC1014": "MECHANICS"
        },
        {
            "FHCT1024": "PROGRAMMING CONCEPT AND DESIGN"
        }
    ]
}

def updateCourse(l):
    upLoop = True
    while upLoop == True:
        os.system('cls')
        print("\nEdit \t <1>Course code \t <2>Course Name \t\t <E>xit")
        updateOption = input("Enter Instruction: ") 
        if updateOption == '1':
            codeUpLoop = True
            while codeUpLoop == True:
                codeToEdit = input("Enter Course Code to Edit: ")
                with open("dict.json",'r') as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                    course = data['courseInfo']
                    if codeToEdit in l :
                        newCourseCode = input("Enter New Course Code: ")
                        for i in course:
                            if i.get(codeToEdit) != None:
                                global temp
                                temp = i.get(codeToEdit) #temp = value of code to edit
                                # Delete Course
                                del i[codeToEdit]
                            course.remove({})
                        else:
                            pass
                        open('dict.json', 'w').close()
                        with open("dict.json", 'r+') as f:
                            json.dump(data, f, indent = 4)
                        # Modify Course Code
                        with open("dict.json", 'r+') as f:
                            data = json.load(f)
                            course = data["courseInfo"]
                        for i in course:
                            if newCourseCode not in l:
                                x = {newCourseCode: temp}
                                course.append(x)
                                with open("dict.json", 'r+') as f:
                                    f.seek(0)
                                    json.dump(data, f, indent = 4)
                                os.system('cls')
                                print("Course Updated Successfully\nPress Enter to cotinue or Enter C to quit")
                                codeUpOp = input()
                                if codeUpOp == 'C'or codeUpOp == 'c':
                                    codeUpLoop = False
                            else:
                                print("Course alredy exist")   
                    else: 
                        os.system('cls')
                        print("Course Not Found\nEnter Y to add Course")
                        add = input("")
                        if add != 'Y' or add != 'y':
                            codeUpLoop = False
l = ['FHSC1014', 'FHCT1012'] # get key from the dictionary file from another function                  
updateCourse(l)
```

This code is to update dictionary file stored in a JSON file. I want to get input of course code from the user and edit it. The `codeUpLoop` is to control the loop of getting and editing the course code. The code was expected to exit `codeUpLoop` when c or not y is entered but it never happen.
Also welcome any recommendation (especially on file management) to improve the code.

Comment: it looks like the only way to exit the while loop is if `codeToEdit` is not in the input parameter `l`.  But your file handling is pretty terrible.  you open and close the same file multiple times all while you are still inside the `with open(...)` clause of the same file.  You even open and close the same file on the same line for no reason at all.

Comment: Please provide a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you familiar with *break* ?

Comment: Nested openings of the same file is rarely wise.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the value of `upLoop` never changes.

On line #4 you have the `while uploop == "True"` which of course will always return True, and nowhere in your function do you ever set the value of `upLoop` to anything else, which means it will continue to loop over and over.

You need either need to `break`, `return` or set the value of `upLoop` to something False if you ever want to exit the function.

In other words there is nothing wrong with the `while codeUpLoop` block, that loop can exit just fine, the issue is that when it exits the code just goes back to the top of `while upLoop` and then `codeUpLoop` get's set to True all over again.

```
def updateCourse(l):
    upLoop = True
    while upLoop == True:  # this loop never exits
        os.system('cls')
        displayCourse()
        print("\nEdit \t <1>Course code \t <2>Course Name \t\t <E>xit")
        updateOption = input("Enter Instruction: ")
        if updateOption == '1':
            codeUpLoop = True    # this keeps getting set to True
            while codeUpLoop == True:
                codeToEdit = input("Enter Course Code to Edit: ")
                data = json.load(open("dict.json",'r'))
                course = data['courseInfo']
                if codeToEdit in l :
                    newCourseCode = input("Enter New Course Code: ")
                    for i in course:
                        if i.get(codeToEdit) != None:
                            global temp
                            temp = i.get(codeToEdit)
                            del i[codeToEdit]
                        course.remove({})
                    else:
                        pass
                    with open("dict.json", 'r+') as f:
                        json.dump(data, f, indent = 4)
                    course = data["courseInfo"]
                    for i in course:
                        if newCourseCode not in l:
                            x = {newCourseCode: temp}
                            course.append(x)
                            with open("dict.json", 'r+') as f:
                                json.dump(data, f, indent = 4)
                            os.system('cls')
                            print("Course Updated Successfully\nPress Enter to cotinue or Enter C to quit")
                            codeUpOp = input()
                            if codeUpOp == 'C'or codeUpOp == 'c':
                                codeUpLoop = False
                        else:
                            print("Course alredy exist")
                else:
                    os.system('cls')
                    print("Course Not Found\nEnter Y to add Course")
                    add = input("")
                    if add == 'Y' or add == 'y':
                        addCourse(l)
                        codeUpLoop = False
                    else:
                        codeUpLoop = False
        elif updateOption == 'E' or updateOption == 'e':
            upLoop = False
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
            time.sleep(1)
```

In addition to the issues stated above file handling has a lot of room for improvement.  I tried to fix some of it above but without a reproducible example it's difficult to know what your intent is.